# Where to find state.sql for sqlserver mode sessionsates?

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for the state.sql file provided by the .NET framework to run sessionstates in sqlserver mode. Where can I find the sql file to create the required tables and stored procs. I tried in the FRAMEWORKS/VERSION2.0 folder but I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](http://www.dbazine.com/sql/sql-articles/cook9) has a great overview of both modes (temporary and persistent db), and the script is linked to from there also...

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20090125002628/http://www.dbazine.com/sql/sql-articles/cook9

Answer (score 1):

It's not `state.sql` anymore, but `InstallSqlState.sql` or `InstallPersistSqlSate.sql`.

Choose `InstallSqlState.sql`, if you would like to store your session data into tempdb (and thus to lose all sessions on every SQL Server restart). Or choose `InstallPersistSqlState.sql` if you would like to store them persistently.